# Comment traduire « relatives » et « parents ». Ambiguïté ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

D'après le dictionnaire, il semble que les deux peuvent être traduits par *parents*. C'est correct?

Comment est-ce que je peux traduire :

> I will meet my relatives tomorrow

C'est possible d'utiliser « parents » ici, sans que ça prête à confusion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Oui**, *parents* peut vouloir dire *parents* ou *relatives*, **mais** ce que me dit mon intuition c'est que *parents* dans le sens de *relatives* s'emploie essentiellement dans l'expression *être un parent de/à*.

« C'est un parent à vous ? » ne choquera pas, même si ça me paraît très formel, voir guindé. Par contre « je vais voir des parents » me fait plus penser au fait d'aller voir les parents (le père et la mère) de quelqu'un d'autre, en particulier des *parents d'élèves*. Pour dire « *I will meet my relatives* », je dirais plutôt « Je vais voir des parents *à moi* »

Par contre « je vais voir *mes* parents » a en principe toujours le sens de « *I will meet my parents* ».

Sinon, pour traduire « *I will meet my relatives tomorrow* », le plus naturel pour moi serait de ne pas parler de *parents*, mais plutôt de *famille*

> Je vais voir ma famille demain.

ou encore

> Je vais voir de la famille demain.

Comment: +1 pour *de la famille*, qui traduit mieux *relatives*, d'après moi (en tout cas, c'est plus simple que commme tu dis le guindé *des parents*).

Comment: *Ah tiens ? Vous êtes parents ?!*, ou bien *Je loge actuellement chez des parents éloignés* ne me semblent pas des expressions si guindées que ça, notamment dans le second exemple pour faire l'économie d'une (potentiellement longue) explication sur le lien de parenté.

Comment: En tout cas, *de la famille* est une bonne traduction pour l'exemple initial. Variantes possibles : *Je vais [passer la journée] dans la famille.* ou *Je vais [passer la journée] en famille.*

Comment: @RomainVALERI C'est vrai que ce n'est pas si guindé que ça, mais ce n'est vraiment pas dans mon idiolecte.

Answer (score 4):

Oui, c'est bien le même mot en français (*parents*) qui porte les sens de ces deux mots anglais (*parents, relatives*). Et ce sera donc souvent l'article qui permettra de faire la distinction.

Exemples :

Pour dire *I will meet my parents tomorrow*, on dira sans amibiguité possible :

> Je vais voir **mes** parents demain.

Et chacun saura que je fais référence à mes ascendants directs (père et mère).

La partie plus délicate est la traduction de *relatives*. Principalement, on aura recours à l'usage d'un article indéfini pour signifier que l'on parle d'un membre de la famille dont l'éloignement et la relation exacte ne sont pas précisés.

En prenant cette légère variante de la phrase initialement proposée *I will meet some relatives tomorrow*, on aura quelque chose comme :

> Je vais voir **des** parents demain.

Ce qui donne, pour rendre l'aspect plus possessif apporté par le *my* de la phrase initiale (*I will meet my relatives tomorrow*) :

> Je vais voir des parents **à moi** demain.

Par contre, l'utilisation d'un possessif singulier (*mon, ma parent(e)*) correspond plutôt à *relative* et non à *parent*.

Et donc en règle générale, en dehors de l'expression *mes parents* ou d'un contexte permettant clairement de comprendre que l'on fait référence aux parents (ascendants directs) de quelqu'un d'autre, *parent* aura le sens de *relatives*.

- my parents >>> mes parents
- your parents >>> tes parents
- my relatives >>> des parents [à moi] (partie entre crochets facultative)
- a relative >>> un parent

---

**Note** : on trouve rarement *un parent* tout seul, il est plus souvent qualifié d'une manière ou d'une autre (*un parent éloigné*, *un de mes parents*, ou simplement *un parent à moi*). Et l'utilisation du terme semble se raréfier il me semble, hors des sphères littéraire et administrative.

Answer (score 0):

Je pensais à verser une réponse en anglais, reposée sur http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1302431&p=6638022#post6638022

> **L'utilisateur LNSEVI :** « parent » means any kind of relative, though it's commonly used for fathers and mothers. For distinction, say "Les proches des personnes ..., ou les familles des personnes ..."
>
> **L'utilisateur thbruxelles :** Indeed «» les proches » could also be close friends. « La famille » sounds better than « les familles » (you only have one family), but it is the word we would use. « Parent » is not false, but we tend to use it referring to relatives older than you. LNSEVI's suggestion of « famille » sounds right.

Exemples de **L'utilisateur zapspan :** suivis de réactions de **L'utilisateur agphledy91 (en tant que puces)** et de **L'utilisateur Lly4n4 (en tant que losanges) :**

> 1) *I live with my parents* = J'habite avec mes parents

Here it only means father and mother. There is no ambiguity. This can't mean "relatives."

> 2) *One of your parents must sign this form* =

● Soit votre mère soit votre père doit signer ce formulaire.
● Ou votre mère ou votre père doit signer ce formulaire.
● [Somehow, "Un de vos parents doit signer ce formulaire"

♦ L'un de vos deux parents doit signer ce formulaire (either your mom or your dad).
♦ Un parent doit signer... (one relative, maybe a legal guardian)

> 3) *He's a relative of mine* =
>   ● Lui, c'est un de mes parents.
>   ● Lui, c'est mon parent.
>   ● Lui, c'est un parent.
>   ● Lui, il est en parenté avec moi.

These all seem a bit odd to me, although I suppose that they are not ambiguous. Even the ones with "parent", if correct, are not ambiguous; one would use "père" instead of "parent" if the person is one's father.
They all sound odd to me. Personally I would never use it in the singular form except in the phrase « c'est un parent éloigné » (a distant relative).

I would say : « nous sommes parents », nous sommes de la même famille ».

Lui, c'est:
♦ un parent (a relative)
♦ un parent éloigné (a distant relative, as said before)
♦ quelqu'un de ma famille (colloquial)
♦ un membre de ma famille (neutral).